# How to access all sub list elements in R at once?

Tags: r, list

I have a splitted string of a vector like

```
df <- c("Test A:No1", "Test B:No2")
l <- str_split(df, ":")
l
```

which returns me

```
[[1]]
[1] "Test A" "No1" 

[[2]]
[1] "Test B" "No2"
```

Now I am interested in accessing all first elements and all last elements independently or create a vector like

```
[1] "Test A" "Test B"
```

and

```
[1] "No1" "No2"
```

I tried several types of single and double brackets, with and without commas, but l[[x]][1] or l[[x]][2] give me only the list element x.

How can I access all elements at once (e.g. l[[]][1] )?

Comment: See `?data.table::tstrsplit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `sapply`.

```
sapply(l, `[`, 1)
# [1] "Test A" "Test B"

sapply(l, `[`, 2)
# [1] "No1" "No2"
```

*Explanation:* In R quite everything is a function. Also the parentheses `` `[` `` actually are functions. Considering following example makes clear why the `sapply` above works.

**Example**

Consider this vector

```
x <- c("A", "B")
```

Whey we're doing

```
x[1]
# [1] "A"
x[2]
# [2] "B"
```

we're actually applying the special form of the underlying prefix-form of the `` `[` `` function:

```
`[`(x, 1)
# [1] "A"
`[`(x, 2)
# [1] "B"
```

Comment: This works.But why? Applying a function " [ " on the whole list? And how would I know, that the parameters 1 and 2 would work?

Comment: @StefanL. I should have added explanation earlier; `1` resp. `2` denote the location of the vector element in the lists. You may read more of this in [Hadley Wickam's Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#special-forms).

Comment: This is what I want !!! Thank you~~~

Answer (score 0):

maybe using unlist and lapply can get the work done.

```
df <- c("Test A:No1", "Test B:No2")
l <- str_split(df, ":")

> unlist(lapply(l,function(x) x[1]))
[1] "Test A" "Test B"
> unlist(lapply(l,function(x) x[length(x)]))
[1] "No1" "No2"
```